# When do we include infinity in intervals in measure theory?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am a beginner to measure theory (coming from a physics background and learning it for stochastic calculus). I have noticed very often in measure theory, oftentimes do I see closed intervals with $[a,+\infty]$ instead of the usual $[a,+\infty)$ that I am used to. I also see people use $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ instead of just $\mathbb{R}$ When do we include infinity in our intervals? Why is this allowed? Is there any intuition behind the differences when infinity is included or not? Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'allowed'? You can look at whatever you want to. However, very naturally in measure theory, you will have to deal with objects with an infinite measure or positive functions with an infinite integral. It's not, in essence, any different from the fact that when doing general mathematics, you will naturally want to consider infinite sets.

Comment: what I mean is, for example, if we want to analyse the integrability of a function, is there a difference between the integrability over [a, infinity) and [a, infinity]?

Comment: Depends on your measure. If your measure on $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ is non-atomic, then no. If you're considering, say, Dirac mass at $\infty$, then there is very much a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $+\infty$ is usually included in the range of a measure. From the very beginning, it is inevitable to consider the measure of a set in the form of $[a,+\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

If we allow to define $a+(+\infty)=+\infty$ for any finite number $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$\mu([0,1]\cup[2,+\infty))=\mu([0,1])+\mu([2+\infty))$ holds as a specific case for the general property of a measure: $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ for any $A, B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Thus, we usually write down a measure as $\mu:\mathcal{B}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}\cup \{+\infty\}$.

I think it is for simplicity.

Comment: And then if the zero function is integrated over a set of infinite measure the integral should be zero, so $0\cdot \infty=0$.